# Turning if statements to while loops

Tags: python

```
rent_expense_choose = str(input("Do you want a Custom rent expense integer or the Industry 
Standard, please enter C for custom and IS for industry standard: "))
if rent_expense_choose == "C":
    rent_expense = float(input("Please input the percentage of the rent which will be 
dedicated to expenses, awnser as a decimal e.g 0.24 = 24%: "))
elif rent_expense_choose == "IS":
    rent_expense = int(0.24)
else: print("please input either C or IS")
```

I want to turn this code into a while loop and I will explain how the loop will work. So the code asks for an input either C or IS, if the input is C the user will be prompted with an input and be asked another question but if the input is IS rent_expense will be assigned the value 0.24. What I wanted to do is create a while loop which when the user input is not either C or IS it loops the question again until the user inputs either C or IS so the code can move forward. Would appreciate some help and if the question seems stupid please don't flame me because i'm new.

Comment: You could wrap the entire code fragment in *while True:*. Note that *int(0.24) == 0*. Note also that converting the return value of *input()* to *str* is pointless as it's already a string type. Elsewhere you convert the return from *input()* to *float* without allowing for bad input. This could cause an unwanted Exception

Answer (score 0):

```
rent_expense_choose = ""
while rent_expense_choose not in ["C", "IS"]:
    rent_expense_choose = str(input(">"))
```

And the rest of your code with ifs.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work, if you want to do it with a while loop

```
rent_expense_choose = ""
while rent_expense_choose not in ("IS", "C"):
    print("please input either C or IS")
    rent_expense_choose = input("Do you want a Custom rent expense integer or the Industry "
                                "Standard, please enter C for custom and IS for industry standard: ").upper()

if rent_expense_choose == "C":
    rent_expense = float(input("Please input the percentage of the rent which will be "
                               "dedicated to expenses, awnser as a decimal e.g 0.24 = 24%: "))
elif rent_expense_choose == "IS":
    rent_expense = 0.24
```

And if you don't trust the user to write an exact input in the first instance, you probably want to have some error handling when getting the float too.

Your `rent_expense_choose == "IS":` were also converted to an int, meaning 0. You don't have to specify data type, you can just write `rent_expense = 0.24` if yo uwant it as a float.

Comment: Why *rent_expense = int(0.24)*? *rent_expense = 0* is equivalent

Comment: Was just copied from original question, was just about to make an edit about that...

Comment: Appreciate the help, I actually understand while loops now based on the format you showed me. Lots of people don't respect beginner level programmers i'm not sure why, I get flamed all the time for being "Bad". Appreciate the help.